# Tamanho de uma tabela Mysql com 200 milhões de registros

Tags: mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para um cliente, e me deparei com a seguinte  situação: ele me passou um banco de dados, com números de telefones. E tenho que criar uma rotina, para gerar novos números para futuras consultas.

A tabela recebera cerca de **200 milhões** de registros, com 3 campos `ID - NÚMERO E CÓDIGO` - meu medo é se a tabela em `MYSQL` irá suportar sem problemas.

O sistema ficará rodando durante 4 dias para gerar todos os dados, comecei hoje a tarde, já esta com **15 milhões** de registros e com quase **600 megas**.

A tabela não terá vários acessos simultâneos, será somente para gerar um relatório de dados com o mesmo código!

Comment: Eu pensei nisso, o problema e o seguinte, tenho que saber o numero de telefone e de determinada operadora, e assim passar para o cliente, quantos números ele possui de uma determinada operadora, e de um determinado DDD.
Eu pensei que seria somente quando realizasse a consulta, ate ai tudo bem, não seria preciso criar uma base para consulta, mais o cliente quer que seja exibido a quantidade de acordo como descrevi acima

Comment: Isso, posso tirar o ID, mais acabei de lembrar que precisarei do DDD

Comment: Já trabalhei em um sistema que tinha uma tabela no MySQL que num belo dia precisou de uma mudança emergencial porque estourou o tamanho da chave, que era int(10).

Comment: @Bacco É porque o formato dela tinha sido copiado de um outro sistema. Mas depois disso, só tive certeza que é melhor pecar pelo exagero do que pela falta. Colocamos int(18) lá e o sistema segue feliz até hoje.

Comment: Esta demorando cerca de 5 segundos para pegar um prefixo com DDD, depois gerar 10 mil números por prefixo e gravar no BD, depois que tudo estiver pronto e que irei processar o Codigo da operadora de acordo com o numero gerado, 

5 segundos X 52 mil prefixos, pelas minhas contas mal feitas acho que daria uns 3 dias e algumas horas

Se eu fosse gerar ja com o código da operadora, estava subindo para 30 segundos gerando o código para cada numero, ai subiria para quase 30 dias !!!

Comment: Marcos, as suas colunas são indexadas? Por DDD e número (nesta ordem)? Porque se não forem, você está ferrado.

Comment: Na verdade pensei melhor e vou deixar o numero inteiro ex 11999999999 - estes números serão atualizados a cada 5 meses, mais acho que vou estudar uma forma de so alterar os que aparecerem na lista de portabilidade, assim não precisa processar tudo novamente.

Comment: @Bacco Boa, ja vai ser a solução para o próximo passo!!

Comment: Cara, existe a possibilidade de usar o SQL Server Express 2016? Ele é free tbm, o único limite é que seu banco não poderá passar de 10 GB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1338/3473971) do SO em inglês:

> O tamanho fisico do BD nao importa. O numero de linhas nao importa.
>
> Na minha experiencia, o maior problema que voce vai ter nao é o tamanho, mas o numero de queries que pode suportar em um determinado momento.
>
> Meu BD tem mais de 10GB e com um numero moderado de conexoes, nao tem problema com as requisicoes.

Esta outra [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14733561/3473971) do SO em inglês, o usuário diz que teve tabelas com 200-300 milhões de registros, com tamanho acima de 1TB sem problemas. É uma questão de saber executar.

**Resumindo, não, não tem problema**. Mas te recomendo fortemente dar uma boa lida na documentação, nessas respostas, trabalhar com indices, as vezes conversar com um DBA experiente.

Comment: Valew Leofontes, assim fico mais tranquilo, quanto as requisições não vou ter muitos problemas, ate mesmo pq e u sistema fechado, e poucas pessoas farão a consulta, mais com certeza tenho que pensar em uma futura migração de sistema, e assim ja criar a estrutura enxuta para não ter problemas futuros!!